# PHP usort string with numbers correctly

Tags: php, string, object, usort

I would like to usort an object by one of its elements but I'm not sure how to do a string comparison on a string which contains numbers and the position of the number is not always the same.

for example in my case the values I would like to sort look like this:
`String (A), String (B), String bit longer 1, String bit longer 2, String bit longer 3, String bit longer 10, String bit longer 20` (But not in this order)

if I do a simple strcmp() comparison usort will sort it like mysql would so the order will look like this: `String (A), String (B), String bit longer 1, String bit longer 10, String bit longer 2, String bit longer 20, String bit longer 3` which is wrong

Now I'm stuck and don't what should I do to sort it correctly.

EDIT:

the object I'm trying to sort looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        ( [field] => String (A) ... lots of other fields )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        ( [field] => String (B) ... lots of other fields )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        ( [field] => String bit longer 1 ... lots of other fields )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        ( [field] => String bit longer 2 ... lots of other fields )
    ...and so on
)
```

Comment: You want to do a natural sort?

Comment: Have you looked at `natsort()`?

Comment: so what would be the correct sorting?

Comment: @Ghost the correct sorting would be like in my first example 1,2,3,10,20

Comment: @LaciK then you could use Mark Reeds answer below, should be the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting arrays of strings, you can use [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php):

```
php > print_r($ary);
Array
(
    [0] => String (A)
    [1] => String (B)
    [2] => String bit longer 1
    [3] => String bit longer 10
    [4] => String bit longer 2
    [5] => String bit longer 20
    [6] => String bit longer 3
)
php > natsort($ary);
php > print_r($ary);
Array
(
    [0] => String (A)
    [1] => String (B)
    [2] => String bit longer 1
    [4] => String bit longer 2
    [6] => String bit longer 3
    [3] => String bit longer 10
    [5] => String bit longer 20
)
```

For a property of a larger object, use the comparison function used by `natsort`, `strnatcmp`, in a custom comparison function that you pass to `usort`:

```
function natcmpfield($obj1, $obj2) {
   return strnatcmp($obj1->fieldName, $obj2->fieldName);
}

usort($objArray, natcmpfield);
```

For example:

```
php > print_r($objArray);
Array
(
    [0] => Example Object ( [str] => String (A))
    [1] => Example Object ( [str] => String (B))
    [2] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 1)
    [3] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 10)
    [4] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 2)
    [5] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 20)
    [6] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 3)
)
php > function natcmpfield($obj1, $obj2) {
    { return strnatcmp($obj1->str, $obj2->str);
    { }
php > usort($objArray, natcmpfield);
php > print_r($objArray);
Array
(
    [0] => Example Object ( [str] => String (A))
    [1] => Example Object ( [str] => String (B))
    [2] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 1)
    [3] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 2)
    [4] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 3)
    [5] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 10)
    [6] => Example Object ( [str] => String bit longer 20)
)
```

Comment: Thank you it works now correctly. I don't know what happend but first it sorted totally worong like 1,2,10,20,3,4,22,23 than after reuploading the edited file it worked like charm.